# Is $C_c^\infty$ dense in $L^p$ when $p<1$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $0<p<1$ and $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$, does there exists $g\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $||f-g||_p<\epsilon$? I know this is true when $p\geq 1$, but not sure how to prove this when $p<1$.

I have proven that $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Hence, it suffices to show that for any $f\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\epsilon>0$, there exists $g\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $||f-g||_p<\epsilon$. But how?

Comment: can you explain this theorem if you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Simple functions with bounded support are dense in $L^p(\mathbb R^n), 0 < p < \infty.$ So it is enough to prove it for $\chi_E,$ where $E$ is measurable and bounded.